# Binary search trees - removing odd nodes

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm doing an exercise on Binary Search Trees, where I need to be removing odd nodes and at the end printing the key value of each node in a single line considering the pre-order path.
I couldn't identify what could be wrong
Here is my code

```
struct Node* remove_odd_nodes(struct Node* root) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    root->left = remove_odd_nodes(root->left);
    root->right = remove_odd_nodes(root->right);
    if (root->value % 2 == 1) {
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
            free(root);
            return NULL;
        }
        if (root->left == NULL) {
            struct Node* temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        if (root->right == NULL) {
            struct Node* temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        struct Node* min_node = root->right;
        while (min_node->left != NULL) {
            min_node = min_node->left;
        }
        root->value = min_node->value;
        root->right = remove_odd_nodes(root->right);
    }
    return root;
}
```

I couldn't identify what could be wrong

Comment: What does "remove odd nodes" mean?  It isn't obvious what the phrase means, let alone why you expect the output that you say you're supposed to get.  Maybe add a diagram?

Comment: Note: `if (root->value % 2 == 1)` should be `if (root->value % 2 != 0)` to detect negative odds too.

Comment: @btilly 
my input is a binary tree that I need to traverse and remove the sibling nodes. what did you not understand?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica 
I will make this change and test. Thank you

Comment: I took the entrance test.
12
28
15
13
18
10
12
50
35
42
65
53
70
and the output is 
28 18 10 12 18 50 42 70 
it's almost right the only problem is that the number 18 repeats twice

Comment: @marianaUser01 I do not understand how `10` is in the input but is not in the desired output. Despite it being even. If "remove a node" means simply removing it and all children from the tree, that would be plausible.  But you've got logic to keep at least some of the tree below a removed node.  So why does `10` disappear from the output?

Comment: @btilly Sorry. 10 is the number of input numbers. It was my mistake to put it together with the other numbers. Input is 41,20,11,29,32,65,50,91,72,99

Comment: I think you should also test it on all odd nodes to verify that it is empty after removing odd nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified test harness for anyone to use.

I replaced manual input with coded input.

```
int main() {
  struct Node *root = NULL;
#if 0
  int n, value;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &value);
    root = insert_node(root, value);
  }
#else
  //10,41,20,11,29,32,65,50,91,72,99
  root = insert_node(root, 41);
  root = insert_node(root, 20);
  root = insert_node(root, 11);
  root = insert_node(root, 29);
  root = insert_node(root, 32);
  root = insert_node(root, 65);
  root = insert_node(root, 50);
  root = insert_node(root, 91);
  root = insert_node(root, 72);
  root = insert_node(root, 99);
#endif
  print_preorder(root);
  printf("\n");
  root = remove_odd_nodes(root);
  print_preorder(root);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Ouptut

```
41 20 11 29 32 65 50 91 72 99 
50 20 32 72 50 72
```

Comment: the desired output is 50,20,32, 72

Comment: @marianaUser01 Confident the issue is in `struct Node *min_node = root->right; while (min_node->left != NULL) { min_node = min_node->left; }  root->value = min_node->value;  root->right = remove_odd_nodes(root->right);`.

Comment: @marianaUser01 Getting closer: `root->value = min_node->value;` copy the key, good, but `root->right = remove_odd_nodes(root->right);` does not remove the key (which is even)  from the right.

Comment: I still couldn't understand how I can correct the code to receive the desired output

Comment: @marianaUser01 Various ways to handle this.  Some make for a lop-sided tree, other more flat.  Hmmmm.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out already, the bug is here.

```
    struct Node* min_node = root->right;
    while (min_node->left != NULL) {
        min_node = min_node->left;
    }
    root->value = min_node->value;
    root->right = remove_odd_nodes(root->right);
```

You're copying the correct value to `root`.  But you're also leaving it where it comes from.  So now the value appears twice.  You need to patch up the tree to remove it from where it was.

Separately you're trying to remove the odd nodes again, despite that you already did that before this section.  That's a performance bug.

So change to something like this (untested):

```
    if (root->right->left == NULL) {
        root->right->left = root->left;
        struct Node* old_root = root;
        root = root->right;
        free(old_root);
    }
    else {
        struct Node* min_node_parent = root->right;
        while (min_node_parent->left->left != NULL) {
            min_node_parent = min_node_parent->left;
        }
        struct Node* min_node = min_node_parent->left;
        root->value = min_node->value;
        min_node_parent->left = min_node->right;
        free(min_node);
    }
```

Comment: you solved my problem thanks the code is working